# How to use mysql to find a field name of a record?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDO sql codes :

```
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $gg = join('</td><td>', $r);
    echo "<tr><td>" . $no_count . "</td><td>" . $gg . "</td></tr>";
    $no_count = $no_count + 1;      
}
```

variable `$r` is the record, how can I echo the field name of `$r`?

Let's say `$r` carry records from 2 different fields "product" and "price". The value of `$r` is "apple", "130". How can I add "usd" into "130"?

I need something like.... `if $field_name == "$r['price']" { $r = join('usd', $r); };`

Thanks to Mike B, I almost there :

```
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            foreach ($r as $name => $value) {
                if ($name == "price"){
                     $r = "usd" . $value; // this line got problem, how to change the value in an array variable $r?
                }
            }

            $gg = join('</td><td>', $r);
            echo "<tr><td>" . $no_count . "</td><td>" . $gg . "</td></tr>";
            $no_count = $no_count + 1;              
}
```

Comment: Just a little improvement, run this little piece of code after you connect to your database to remove the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` from your `fetch()` method: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` It defaults all fetches to FETCH_ASSOC, makes things look cleaner down the road.

Comment: @zac1987, in the code you provided I can't see how `$r` is 130 since `$r` is only ever assigned the return of `PDOStatement::fetch()` which returns an associative-array when passed `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. Maybe you're showing us the wrong code? You only use `$r` once as an argument to `join()`. `var_dump($r);` at the top of the loop and you'll see the structure.

Comment: @Mike B, the field name can be "price" only when the user select it. But when user didn't select it, the field name won't has "price" anymore. This is my sql select statement : `$sql = "SELECT " . $setting_name_left_with_sign . " FROM sale";` . As you can see i don't know the field name because the field name is inside the array variable.

Comment: @Mike B, Yes, I don't know how to work with array... I have updated my question. Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_keys($r)` will get you a list of fields from the table since you're fetching an associative array.

You can also loop through `$r`:

```
foreach ($r as $name => $value) {
  print "$name: " . $value;
}
```

### Update

// this line got problem, how to change the value in an array variable $r?

```
$r[$name] = 'usd' . $value;
```

Make the edit to the original name. Since you have the key in the `$name` variable from the foreach loop you can set it directly.

Comment: I see. Perfect!! $r[$name] is a new thing for me. Learn something new from you. Thank you very much. U are my hero >.<